# Check if a view is displayed in WebView with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

How can I check that a view (any view, TextBox, Button) is displayed in a WebView, using Espresso?

I have tried with the following, but I'm not able to finish the check:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(ID, "username")).check( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(ID, "username")).check( ... )
```

with this:

```
onWebView().check(webContent(hasElementWithId("username"));
```

Worked for me.